# How to select the HTML5 data attribute in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, attributes

My current jQuery selects the value attribute. How do I change my jQuery to select the data attribute "data-price"?

```
$('#trapfabric, #trapsize').on('change', function() {
  var $selected = $('#trapfabric, #trapsize').children(":selected");
  sum = parseInt($('#trapsize').val()) + parseInt($('#trapfabric').val());
  $('#priceToSwap3').html('$' + sum
    );
});
```

I know I have to fit something like this in the above but I can't get it to work:

```
$('#priceToSwap3').text($selected.data("price"))
```

EDITED

My HTML:

```
<span id="priceToSwap3"">$238</span>

<select id="trapsize" onChange="swapImage()">
 <option data-price="238">foo</option>
 <option data-price="288">foo</option>
</select>

<select id="trapfabric" onChange="swapImage()">
 <option data-price="0">foo</option>
 <option data-price="20">foo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't see data-price anywhere in your script.  Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: It does not makes any sense, why not to use the input value?

Comment: @Felix Kling I have posted my HTML.

Comment: @roXon I can't use value because I have more than 1 value to each option.

Comment: @FelixKling I have edited the jQuery to include $selected. Please take a look. I still can't get it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
var $elements = $('#trapfabric, #trapsize');
$elements.on('change', function() {
     var $selected = $elements.children(":selected");
     var sum = 0;

     $selected.each(function() {
         sum += $(this).data('price');
     });

     $('#priceToSwap3').html('$' + sum);
});
```

You have to iterate over the selected elements to get the `price` datum of each of them.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uHddF/)

Answer (score 0):

You are binding event to two elements `#trapsize`, `#trapfabric` if you want to get the `source` element you need to use `$(this)`;

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/pGZuW/)

```
$('#trapfabric, #trapsize').on('change', function() {    
    $('#priceToSwap3').text( '$' + $(':selected', this).data("price") );
});
```

Comment: Hi Adil, I am new to jQuery. Where do I add this line of code so that I could replace the value attribute?

Comment: Adil, I thought it would have been weird to make my own answer, since it's really not that different, so I edited your answer after the op gave the related html. @ElijahYang There's a jsfiddle example in the above answer now.

Comment: Thanks @Joonas, so nice of you.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar scenario wherein we assign security value(1,2,3 as security level) for each input. We have to change the security values "0" when the user logs into the system.

Eg:

```
<input type="text" security="3" id="super-admin" />
<input type="text" security="2" id="main-admin" />
<input type="text" security="1" id="normal-user" />

<script>
function userValidation(userType){

if(userType="super-admin"){
   $("[security=1]").attr("security", 0);
   $("[security=2]").attr("security", 0);
   $("[security=3]").attr("security", 0);
 }
if(userType="main-admin"){
  $("[security=1]").attr("security", 0);
  $("[security=2]").attr("security", 0);
 }
 if(userType="normal-user"){
   $("[security=1]").attr("security", 0);
 }
}
<script>
```