# How to use data attribute with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, attributes

My jQuery selects the value attribute. How do I change my jQuery to select the data attribute "data-price"?

HTML:

```
<span id="priceToSwap3"">$238</span>

<select id="trapsize">
 <option data-price="238">item1</option>
 <option data-price="288">item2</option>
</select>

<select id="trapfabric">
 <option data-price="0">item3</option>
 <option data-price="20">item4</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#trapfabric, #trapsize').on('change', function() {
  var $selected = $('#trapfabric, #trapsize').children(":selected");

  sum = parseInt($('#trapsize').val()) + parseInt($('#trapfabric').val());
  $('#priceToSwap3').html('$' + sum
    );
});
```

Comment: Or, even better, `.data('price')`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select the HTML5 data attribute in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156250/how-to-select-the-html5-data-attribute-in-jquery)

Comment: @roXon yes it's a duplicate because I didn't phrase my question properly in the last post and hence it was confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fetch the data attribute `$(el).data('price')`

```
var sum = $('#trapsize option:selected').data('price') + $('#trapfabric option:selected').data('price');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aYXfM/)

Comment: hi Arun, i have tried your suggestion also with parseInt but in my case it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/wesweatyoushop/3H3dA/31/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $('#trapsize option:selected').data('price');
```

using your code

```
$('#trapfabric, #trapsize').on('change', function() {
  sum = parseInt($('#trapsize option:selected').data('price')) + parseInt($('#trapfabric option:selected').data('price'));
  $('#priceToSwap3').html('$' + sum); 
});
```

example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/rN58S/2/)

Answer (score 0):

`$('option').attr('data-price');`

Answer (score 0):

```
attr("data-price");
```

or

```
data("price");
```

The latter being the preferable way.

---

In your code it would be:

```
sum = parseInt($('#trapsize option:selected').data('price')) + parseInt($('#trapfabric option:selected').data('price'));
```

---

More about `data()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $('#trapsize option:selected').data('price');  

 $('#trapfabric option:selected').data('price');
```

And your function should be;

```
$('#trapfabric, #trapsize').on('change', function() {
   sum = parseInt($('#trapsize option:selected').data('price')) + parseInt($('#trapfabric option:selected').data('price'));
   $('#priceToSwap3').html('$' + sum);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery **attr**

```
$("your dom").attr("data-price")
```

Answer (score 0):

even you can get and set values based on the attribute

```
$("[data-price=238]").attr("data-price", 0);
```