# loop and select every element in DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<p class="item" data-price="2" data-qty="1">item 1</p>
<p class="item" data-price="12" data-qty="4">item 2</p>
<p class="item" data-price="4" data-qty="2">item 3</p>
```

how to sum the price and qty of above item using loop? I know how to get the value at times its quantity but how to loop over them?

```
parseInt($('.item').attr('data-price')) * $('.item').attr('data-qty')
```

Comment: @RichardKho I'm stuck at the loop part.

Comment: Use the `jQuery.prototype.each` method.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735342/jquery-to-loop-through-elements-with-the-same-class

Answer (score 2):

Iterate using jQuery.each and sum

```js
var sum = 0;
$(".item").each(function(){
  sum += this.dataset.price * this.dataset.qty;
});

$("h2").html("Result: " + sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p data-price="2" data-qty="1" class="item">item 1</p>
<p data-price="12" data-qty="4" class="item">item 2</p>
<p data-price="4" data-qty="2" class="item">item 3</p>


<h2> </h2>
```

Comment: After edit, the result returns wrong. He missed the class="item" in p tag in edit

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to call HTML 5 data attributes.
Source: [How to select the HTML5 data attribute in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156250/how-to-select-the-html5-data-attribute-in-jquery)

```
var sum = 0;
$("p.item").each(function(i){
    var items = "p.item:eq(" + i + ")";
    sum +=  parseInt($(items).data("price"), 10) * parseInt($(items).data("qty"), 10);
});

$("h3").text(sum);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/17Lrhm6y/4/)